# Неопределенный путь к файлу

Tags: c++, переменные-среды

Я ламер в программировании. Решил написать программу которая будет работать с определенной программой установленной у пользователя на ПК. Её путь `C:\Users\Администратор\AppData\Local` (лично у меня). Знаю, что у других юзеров будет другое Имя пользователя (а не как у меня Администратор).
Вопрос как указать путь к файлам программы расположенной в `%appdata%` если имена пользователей системы разные ?

Answer (score 0):

Вы же сами сказали - в `%appdata%`. Воспользуйтесь этой переменной среды (получить ее значение можно с помощью функции `getenv`) для построения пути к файлу для текущего пользователя.

Вряд ли вас интересует, чтобы программа лазила в чужие папки :)

Comment: Только `%localappdata%`, а не `%appdata%`, судя по приведенному в вопросе пути. :)

Comment: @Yaant Вообще-то да, но тут уж что ТС нужно - хоть `%temp%` :)